# How can I install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside windows 8?

Tags: installation, windows

How can I install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside windows 8? This option doesn't appear in the installation menu

Answer (score 0):

Its easy! All you gotta do is insert your ubuntu CD/USB and boot from it.

Then enter installation , fill in some credentials and when it comes to the stage of asking you where you want to install ubuntu ,

Choose "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows 8.1"